# Copy con doesn't work when using the run commend

Tags: cmd, vbscript

I've tried to write code that will write a file to the user's startup folder.

```
Set Wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Wshell.Run "%COMSPEC% cd \c AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start 
Menu\Programs\Startup & copy con master.vbs & x = 1 & x=2^Z",0,True
```

P.S. I used cd appdata because cmd's default startup folder is C:\Users\[Username] and the startup folder's location is

```
C:\Users\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Comment: CMD has no default startup folder. It runs with the working directory that's either implicitly inherited from the parent process or explicitly set by the parent process. Use `%AppData%` to refer to the user's "AppData\Roaming" folder.

Comment: `ECHO` might prove a better choice than `COPY CON`, depending on how you intend to use it.